# IFC File, React, change elements color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ifc

I use React to develop a simple BIM application and faced the following problem: the customer wants it to be possible to change the colors of certain elements and save them when receiving data from the FastApi backend, Python. That is, to make the eternal illumination of the elements by changing their color.

I used web-ifc and its dependencies, as well as the new openbim-components, but nothing works.

The repository where I tried to do this:

https://github.com/ktaroabobon/ifcjs-react

There is an asynchronous method that uploads the file to the scene, I tried there, but nothing worked. I'm asking for help.

Comment: It can be, for example, a wall or a chair. That is, let's say the ID of the element came from the backend and I want to change the color of the element using this ID. I've tried a lot in these two days, but I couldn't do anything.